# How correctly make fixed title in bootstrap collapse/accordion?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap accordion and It looks next:

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
               <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-body nav-item-box div-shadow" id="headingOne">
                     <h5>
                       <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample" href="#el1">First</a>
                       </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="el1" class="collapse show fade" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<a href="https://www.fiverr.com/sunlimetech/design-and-fix-your-bootstrap-4-issues" class="ml-3" target="_blank"><strong>View More designs <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></strong></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body nav-item-box div-shadow" id="headingTwo">
                                    <h5>
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample" href="#el2">Second</a>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="el2" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.<a href="https://www.fiverr.com/sunlimetech/design-and-fix-your-bootstrap-4-issues" class="ml-3" target="_blank"><strong>View More designs <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></strong></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image]

So can I make "First" and "Second" titles fixed to top when we scroll the content? Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for `position: sticky; top: value` or [bootstrap affix](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)

Comment: thanks , yes It's simmilar what I'm looking for, I try affix to my div "card-body" but It doesn't work , can you show me please how correctly use it in my example code?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using in your code by the way?

Comment: I use bootstrap 4 in my project

Comment: Try using the sticky class found here, I'll write an answer when I get the chance. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/